# Bash script: no output; no error!

Tags: shell-script

I am testing following code that intends to get input from user and after checking some conditions store it to a new variable. However, this code is not giving me any output or error upon running in the shell terminal.
I have given execution permission to the file by `sudo chmod +x test.sh`.

```
#!/bin/bash

counter="0"
iso_val="100"

while [ "$counter" == "3" ]
do
    echo -n "Enter ISO [ 100-800 ]: "; read iso
    if (( "$iso" < "100" )) || (( "$iso" > "800" )); then
        echo "Error!"
    elif [ "$iso" == "" ]; then
        echo "Error!"
    else
        iso_val=$iso
        break
    fi
    counter=$[$counter + 1]
done
```

Comment: You set `counter` to 0 and then started a while loop which only runs when it's 3. O.o Obviously the loop will never run.

Comment: I changed it, still no output.
`counter="1"
iso_val="100"

while [ "$counter" = "3" ]`

Comment: I am increment in counter also. I don't understand what I am doing wrong here. Can you please correct me where it is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script as written runs without error and would not produce output.

A quick note: you should temporarily add `set -x` at the beginning of your `bash` scripts for getting a good start on debugging.

The issue is the line:

```
while [ "$counter" == "3" ]
```

The `do` block following that line would only be run if `$counter` was equal to `3`, but `$counter` will not increment unless that `do` block is ran.

You would need something outside the block you wish to execute to increment your counter.  i.e.

```
#!/bin/bash

counter="0"
iso_val="100"

while [ "$counter" -lt 3 ]
do
    echo -n "Enter ISO [ 100-800 ]: "; read iso
    if [ -z "$iso" ] || [ "$iso" -lt 100 ] || [ "$iso" -gt 800 ]; then
        echo "Error!"
    else
        iso_val=$iso
        break
    fi
    counter=$(($counter + 1))
done
```

I set a limit to how many times `while` is ran, otherwise the script does not exit on error.  I also changed your string comparisons to integer comparisons where I could.

Edit:  New script with clarified requirement from comments, "ask up to three times on error"

Comment: Thank you so much for such a nice explanation. Actually, I want to give 3 tries to the user to enter a value, that is why I am using while loop and counter.

Comment: I made some changes to fit that requirement